# Change getFinalPrice () function magento

Tags: magento-1.8

Good afternoon guys! I wonder if it is possible and what is the file (path) to change `getFinalPrice ()` function in magento, because I need to add some fixed calculations about the product.

Thank you!

Comment: This won't do what you think it will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is in the Price Model for the product type - for the bundle for example in
`app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Price.php`

```
public function getFinalPrice($qty = null, $product)
{
    if (is_null($qty) && !is_null($product->getCalculatedFinalPrice())) {
        return $product->getCalculatedFinalPrice();
    }

    $finalPrice = $this->getBasePrice($product, $qty);
    $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_get_final_price', array('product' => $product, 'qty' => $qty));
    $finalPrice = $product->getData('final_price');

    $finalPrice = $this->_applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $finalPrice);
    $finalPrice += $this->getTotalBundleItemsPrice($product, $qty);

    $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
    return max(0, $product->getData('final_price'));
}
```

And provides you with a nice event that you can use:

```
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_get_final_price', array('product' => $product, 'qty' => $qty));
    $finalPrice = $product->getData('final_price');
```

In your observer for `catalog_product_get_final_price` just use

```
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $product->setFinalPrice($yourCustomPrice);
```

If you need to get the current final price use `$product->getData('final_price')` as `$product->getFinalPrice()` would create an infinite loop.

Comment: You beat me to it. Great descriptive answer.