# Overwrite getSpecialPrice function

Tags: magento-1.9, php, price

I would like to overwrite getSpecialPrice function.

I found this "tutorial":
[Change getFinalPrice () function magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15873/change-getfinalprice-function-magento)

It works perfectly but only when i load one product. If i get collection of products, my new function doesn't work. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1x the final price is not figured during a collection.  It is only calculated on product pages and checkout.  Collections do not go through all the effort to determine the final price, it has proven to be too complex.  That is why during collections final price is not part of the results.
If you have seen the price template you would appreciate how complicated this is

```
    app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml
```